# OpenStack PHP Cloud Manager

Tags: openstack

I have node with clean Ubuntu 12.04.3 and OpenStack installed on it.
Everything works fine and now I  want to make it commercial and sell cloud servers.

Is there any PHP script to easy create cloud servers and some user-mode control panel?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that you take a look at the [OpenStack Dashboard](http://docs.openstack.org/havana/install-guide/install/apt/content/ch_horizon.html) - Horizon; this provides tenants with Web based access to an OpenStack cloud for managing instances etc...